# Angularjs : How to get first index with ng-if?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
  <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in results.groups" ng-if="group.rooms.length > 0"
                   is-open="isOpen" ng-init="isOpen = $index === 0">
```

How do I make isOpen go to $index === 1, when 0 is being hidden by the ng-if?

Comment: It may help to provide some more details about what you are trying to accomplish.  e.g. the accordion should auto open on creation.

Answer (score 0):

Hide it with ng-hide wich will leave the DOM portion and keep the scope. So replace ng-if with ng-hide to achieve this:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in results.groups" ng-show="group.rooms.length > 0" ...>

<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in results.groups" ng-hide="!group.rooms.length > 0" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-show` and `ng-hide` should be working perfectly fine with boolean values (the length of the rooms in your case).

Demo in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JRCmOLAektNar5jWAkGs?p=preview):

```
$scope.groups = [
  { 'name': 'First group', 'rooms': [{'name': 'room101'}] },
  { 'name': 'Second group', 'rooms': [] },
  { 'name': 'Third group', 'rooms': [{'name': 'room301'}] },
]

<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-show="group.rooms.length">{{group.name}}</accordion-group>
```